# If a matrix $G$ is positive semidefinite on hyperplane, then it is positive semidefinite on whole space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry, positive-semidefinite

I'm trying to show this statement:

> Let $G = 1w^T + w1^T - \frac{1}{2}D$ , where $w$ is nonnegative, $z^TDz \leq 0$ for all $z$ such that $1^Tz=0$ and $1^TD1 \geq  0$.
>
> Show that if $z^TGz\geq  0$ for all $z$ such that $1^Tz = 0$, then $z^TGz \geq 0$ for all $z \in \Bbb R^n$.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would try using an orthogonal decomposition of $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $H = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \mid 1^Tv = 0\}$.  $H$ is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (a basis for it is $(1,-1,\ldots), (0,1,-1,\ldots)$, etc.)

The vectors orthogonal to $H$ are precisely the scalar multiples of $1$.
Thus any $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ decomposes as $z = v + a1$ with $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1^Tv = 0$.

If you play with that decomposition and your definition of $G$, the result falls out quickly.

Comment: I've tried your advice and I've got something like this: $$z^TGz = 2a^2n w^T(v+a1)-\frac{1}{2}(v+a1)^TD(v+a1)$$,        but I don't know how to show it's nonnegative. Maybe it's trivial, but I can't see it. Could you possibly help me?

Comment: oh i just noticed that i had misread the question! and on second glance something seems off to me:

Where you say "Show that if $z^TGz \geq 0$ for all $z$ such that $1^Tz =0$, then ..." this does not seem right.  For these $z$, we have $z^TGz = -\frac{1}{2}z^TDz \geq 0$ by assumption already, so we gain no additional information.  Are you sure this is the question you mean to ask?